# Redirect URL and show notification

Tags: html, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

My company has a subdomain that used to house a resource library that's no longer in service. There are hundreds of links that look like **sub.domain.com/some-resource.pdf**. We will be redirecting to **domain.com/new-library**.

We want to do a two-part redirection with a notification of what's happening. The user should first see a message that says "The page you are looking for is not available and you're being redirected now." A few seconds later it should bounce to domain.com/new-library.

I've seen this used on other sites but have no idea how to implement it. I know how to redirect the domain but can someone give me information on how to show the message before changing the page again?

Thanks!

Comment: From the obsoleted URL, generate a redirect to the information page, and on that page use something like a meta-refresh to redirect to the new location after X seconds.

Comment: Is it as simple as that? Redirect once, message, redirect again? Any input on using 301 vs. 302?

Comment: 301 means 'moved permanently', so that would make sense.

Comment: If you redirect with a 301 you should redirect directly to the new location without any meta-refresh page since it doesn't do anything really. What you could do, if you wish to clarify, is to add a check for referer on the new page, and if the referer is the old page, show the message.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for this too and found some help in the comments of the php manual.  You may want to try this:

```
<?php 
 header( "refresh:5;url=domain.com/new-library" ); 
 echo 'The page you are looking for is not available and you will be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="domain.com/new-library">here</a>.'; 
?>
```

Comment: I just saw how old this question is - ah well, perhaps my answer will help someone!